# Listbox item colors on wrong place

Tags: c#

I want to give every group of filenames a different color,
but only the first filename will have a different color in this code,
I can't find anything wrong while debugging the code,
what can be the problem ?...

```
public class ListBoxEx : ListBox
 {
  private string PreviousText = string.Empty;
  private string CurrentText = string.Empty;
  private bool equal = false;

  public ListBoxEx()
  {
     this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
  }

  protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
  {
   try
   {
    e.DrawBackground();

    if (this.Items.Count > 0 && e.Index > 0)
    {
      PreviousText = Path.GetFileName(this.Items[e.Index - 1].ToString());
      CurrentText = Path.GetFileName(this.Items[e.Index].ToString());

      if (CurrentText == PreviousText)
       equal = true;
      else equal = false;

      if (equal)
       e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightYellow), e.Bounds);
      else
       e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue), e.Bounds);

      e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));

  base.OnDrawItem(e);
    }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
    {
    throw (ex);
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how the listbox looks after coloring it and how you expect it to look?

Answer (score 0):

Found it,

```
  string tempFilename = string.Empty;
  SolidBrush Brushcolor;
  bool colorSwitch = false;

protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
 e.DrawBackground();

// Group colors
   string text = this.Items[e.Index].ToString();
   string filename = Path.GetFileName(text);

    if (filename == tempFilename)
     equal = true;
    else equal = false;

    if (equal)
     Brushcolor = ExChangeBrush(!colorSwitch);
    else
    {
     Brushcolor = ExChangeBrush(colorSwitch);
     colorSwitch = !colorSwitch;
    }

    tempFilename = filename;
// end Group colors

   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushcolor, e.Bounds);

   e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));

   base.OnDrawItem(e);
  }
```